# What spectral feature was used to confirm that S0-2 is "single and available"? What is Brγ?

Tags: spectroscopy

The Phys.org article [Astronomers discover S0-2 star is single and ready for big Einstein test](https://phys.org/news/2018-02-astronomers-s0-star-ready-big.html) describes the results of a careful analysis of radial velocity measurements of the star S0-2, which orbits the supermassive black hole at the center of our (Milky Way) galaxy with a period of only 16 years. The paper itself (Devin S. Chu et al, 2018) is available for open access at [ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.04890), and also [ApJ](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/aaa3eb/meta).

The only mention of the word wavelength is in Section 2.2:

> The radial velocity of S0-2 is measured from both data sets by fitting a Gaussian to the Brγ absorption line.

*What exactly is* a Brγ ("Br" + gamma) absorption line?

---

**below:** "The orbit of S0-2 (light blue) located near the Milky Way's supermassive black hole will be used to test Einstein's Theory of General Relativity and generate potentially new gravitational models. Credit: W. M. Keck Observatory (Click for full size)

[image: stars orbiting supermassive black hole center of Milky Way]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brγ is a line in the emission spectrum of Hydrogen, or single-electron (and therefore) hydrogen-like [Rydberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom) atoms in general. In particular, it is the emission due to an electron moving from the 7th to the 4th energy level.

Br is short for [Brackett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series#Brackett_series_(n%E2%80%B2_=_4)), after [Frederik Brackett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Sumner_Brackett), and gamma because

- $\alpha: \ \ 5 \rightarrow 4,$
- $\beta:  \ \ 6 \rightarrow 4,$
- $\gamma: \ \ 7 \rightarrow 4,$

...and so on.

Brγ has a wavelength of 2166nm, as you would get from the [Rydberg formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula), which is well in the infra-red part of the spectrum. It is probably chosen as it has low absorption by the dust towards the centre of the galaxy.

Screenshot from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series#Brackett_series_(n%E2%80%B2_=_4)).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've added some embellishments, feel free to roll back.